# Should you use copy on private slice fields before returning them from getters?

Tags: go

If a `struct` has a private slice field that requires a Getter, should the slice be copied before it gets returned?

I want to confirm if it's safe to return private slices directly from Getters because I don't want callers to be able to modify them through the Getter's return value.

From my testing so far, it seems that returned slices are not linked to the private slice field.
However, I'm not sure if this will be true for all scenarios and I don't want to use `copy` if it's not needed.

Here's what I tried:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Basket struct {
    fruits []string
}

func (b *Basket) Fruits() []string {
    return b.fruits
}

func (b *Basket) AddFruit(fruit string) {
    b.fruits = append(b.fruits, fruit)
}

func main() {
    basket := &Basket{}
    basket.AddFruit("apple")
    basket.AddFruit("banana")
    basket.AddFruit("orange")

    fruits := basket.Fruits()
    fmt.Println(fruits) // [apple banana orange]

    fruits = append(fruits, "mango")
    fruits = append(fruits, "lemon")
    fruits = append(fruits, "pineapple")
    fmt.Println(fruits)          // [apple banana orange mango lemon pineapple]
    fmt.Println(basket.Fruits()) // [apple banana orange]
}
```

And here's what the Getter would look like with `copy`:

```
func (b *Basket) Fruits() []string {
    result := make([]string, len(b.fruits))
    copy(result, b.fruits)
    return result
}
```

Comment: A slice value references (by keeping its address in a pointer-typed variable) its backing array containing the slice's elements as detailed, say, in <https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro> and <https://go.dev/blog/slices>. Hence copying of a slice value (returning a slice from a function is also copying) does not copy the backing array, and both copies _share_ that array. By extension, if you return a slice from a "getter", the callers will be able to mutate the slice's elements.

Comment: The question of whether you _need_ to clone slices to be returned from "getters" only has a quite simple answer: it depends on a particular case—sometimes you want callers to have "their own" copy of the slice's elements, and sometimes you want callers to have references to the original slice's data.

Comment: As @kostix pointed out, whether you want to do defensive copying really depends on the context. One case where it would be desirable is when you're using some slice to configure some middleware. You most likely want to guarantee the concurrency safety of your middleware. If people hold a reference to the slice in question and can change the behaviour of the middleware by updating elements of the slice (without proper synchronisation in place), that would arguably be bad.

Comment: I see, so it **_is_** a good idea to explicitly use `copy` for the scenario in my question. 
@kostix, can you post an Answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kostix mentioned in the comments, it depends on the scenario.

For the one in the OP, we want to use `copy` since we want to keep the Getter's output separate from the private field so callers can't modify it.